# return and scope for jquery each() function within an each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, each

I'm have markup like this:

```
<div class="imagegroup">
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
</div>
<div class="imagegroup">
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
</div>
<div class="imagegroup">
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
</div>​
```

And I want to separately get the height of the tallest image in each group. I've got a jquery `each` function within an `each` function:

```
$('.imagegroup').each(function(index) {
    var tallestHeight = 0;
    var slideshowNumber = index; 
    var slides = $(this).children();

    $(slides).each(function(index) {
        thisSlideHeight = $(this).height();
        console.log("In slideshow #" + slideshowNumber + ", slide #" + index + " has height " + thisSlideHeight);
        if (thisSlideHeight > tallestHeight) {
            var tallestHeight = thisSlideHeight;
        }
        return tallestHeight;
    });

    console.log("For slideshow " + slideshowNumber + " the tallest slide is " + tallestHeight);

});
```

But I'm puzzled as to how to pass the result of the inner each function "one level" up into the "outer" each function without just setting a global variable. `tallestHeight` stays at zero as I've written this.  I realize this is *super* beginner :) All help very appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/m2aJu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `return tallestHeight`, remove it and it will work.

And change `var tallestHeight = thisSlideHeight;` to `tallestHeight = thisSlideHeight;` inside the second each, your should use the outside variable, not declare a new variable.

Or you could simplify your code like below:

```
$('.imagegroup').each(function(index) {
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, $(this).find('img').map(function() {
       return $(this).height();
    }));        
    console.log("For slideshow " + index + " the tallest slide is " + max);
});
```

***[And here is the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m2aJu/1/)***.

Comment: ***var*** tallestHeight = thisSlideHeight;

Comment: @zerkms Yes, I saw that `var` :)

Comment: slightly off-topic, but still relevant: javascript only does function-scope, but not block-scope. It also has hoisting, which bumps the declarations to top of the scope (i.e. function), so while the var inside if should be removed for aesthetic reasons technically the function will still stay the same: https://gist.github.com/3740886